# Why didn't the Doctor just snap his fingers? (spoilers)

Tags: doctor-who

Sorry if this has already been asked, but I couldn't find it.

In "The Name of the Doctor," the initial climax of the show is when

> the GI is pushing the Doctor to say his name and open the doors to the TARDIS by threatening his companions' lives.

We have seen before that the Doctor could snap his fingers in place of anything else to open the doors, so why doesn't he do that here if he is so reluctant to speak his name?

Comment: It seems obvious that the doors to his tomb are locked in some unique way, or else he'd just use his key...

Comment: This has nothing to do with this question except that this  question seems to have caught a lot of flak. I love the moderators and the community on this site. You guys are awesome and are very fastidious in keeping this site clean and on topic!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Snapping his fingers opens the police box doors, which as we saw, were not the doors to the tomb because the doors to the tomb (i.e. the doors that were locked with his name) led to a staircase that headed up toward the console, whereas the police box doors lead directly to the console. Additionally, the Doctor didn't want to open the doors, so even if he *could* have snapped his fingers, he would have refused to do so.

In any event, the police box doors were greatly enlarged by the size leak so opening them would only open the massive exterior shell, not the door to the tomb which was inside the shell (assuming that the TARDIS was even still alive enough by that point to respond to a snap).

Comment: "the Doctor didn't want to open the doors" - yup. It wasn't saying his name that he particularly objected to, it was giving the Great Intelligence access to the contents of the tomb.

Comment: K, thanks! Guess I just read into it the wrong way. Never thought about him not wanting to get in.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, I think he didn't want to say his name anyway. It's some big secret or something.

Comment: @trysis: I guess so. When he found out that River knew his name, he did say that there was only one occasion when he *could* tell her his name, which suggests he wouldn’t usually expect to tell someone his name.